# JS focusout and click autosuggestions on a search input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I built a search-box where I have suggestions displayed as user types in.

```
<div id="search-box">
    <input val="" type="text" id="s" >
    <div id="suggest-box">
      <div class="suggestions">word1</div>
      <div class="suggestions">word2</div>
      <div class="suggestions">word3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I did add for mobile this code so when the user tap "done" on the mobile keyboard the suggestions box closes up and ti doesn't allow me to click on the suggestions

```
    document.addEventListener('focusout', function(e) {
        $("#suggest-box").hide();
    });
```

**the problem** is that the user can't click on the suggestions though...

how to fix it?

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what the question is..

You can't click the suggestions? They're DIV's and are by default not clickable, unless you add an event listener on it, like so:

```
  suggestionElement.addEventListener('click', function()
  {
      input.value = 'suggestion';
  });
```

Here's a basic working suggestion box:

https://jsfiddle.net/76p4z033/1/

Comment: yes of course they are div and they already have a bond...but if i try to click them the searchbox closes before